# Symfony, Doctrine Guard Plugin, generator.yml file, customizing by using another module

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I am using Symfony 1-4 and sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

My question is, on Doctrine Guard Plugin as you know each module came with generator.yml. And i need to customize generator.yml. For example, i need to display another table's (module's) column.

`// for example i am at X module and need to sort according to another table's/module's column
... 


config: 

list: 

sort: [X, asc] // x is not on my module`

Same thing with list/display. I need to display some column which is not on my current module...

I couldn't find it on the web. Thanks a lot for sharing your idea and/or information, erman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Never mind to customize any file directly in the plugin's dir.
2. Override `generator.yml` by copying it into your application's module. The module must be the same name as in plugin. See ["Anatomy of a Plug-in"](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/17-Extending-Symfony#chapter_17_sub_anatomy_of_a_plug_in).
3. Symfony does not provide a built-in functionality to sort items by columns that don't present in current model. You have to do it manually by overriding an `addSortQuery` method in your actions class. See "[Symfony 1.4 admin generator sort on custom column](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2011/01/08/symfony-1-4-admin-generator-sort-on-custom-column/)".

Hope this would help.